# Compute inner dot products of multidimensional numpy array elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What is the most elegant way to compute "inner" dot products of a multidimensional numpy array?

Let's assume I have 2 arrays *a* and *b* both of shape (2, 2, 2) (could be (n, n, 2) with n>= 2) and I want to compute the *inner_dot(a, b)* with the following definition:

```
np.array([[np.dot(a[0, 0, :], b[0, 0, :]), np.dot(a[1, 0, :], b[1, 0, :])],
          [np.dot(a[0, 1, :], b[0, 1, :]), np.dot(a[1, 1, :], b[1, 1, :])]])
```

Here is an example:

```
a = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, 2)
b = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, 2)
```

Expected result:

```
array([[ 1, 41],
       [13, 85]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly multiply both arrays and `sum` along the last axis. Also since you want the top right corner of the output as `np.dot(a[1, 0, :], b[1, 0, :])`, rather than `0,1` and presumably in the same fashion for the off-diagonal elements, you can `transpose` the result to get as expected:

```
(a*b).sum(-1).T
array([[ 1, 41],
       [13, 85]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
In [54]: np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ji',a,b)
Out[54]: 
array([[ 1, 41],
       [13, 85]])
```

With `@ opetator`/ [np.matmul](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
In [16]: (a[:,:,None,:]@b[:,:,:,None])[...,0,0].T
Out[16]: 
array([[ 1, 41],
       [13, 85]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, I run a quick comparison of the run time:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.arange(1024).reshape(64, 8, 2)
b = np.arange(1024).reshape(64, 8, 2)

example_1 = lambda: (a*b).sum(-1).T
print(timeit.timeit(example_1, number=10000))

example_2 = lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ji',a,b)
print(timeit.timeit(example_2, number=10000))

example_3 = lambda: (a[:,:,None,:]@b[:,:,:,None])[...,0,0].T
print(timeit.timeit(example_1, number=10000))
```

On my comupter, the results are (in seconds):

```
example 1: 0.10384939999999787
example 2: 0.05444100000000063
example 3: 0.097186200000003
```